# Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php

Ошибка Can't use function return value in write context in

При таком коде:

```
if (!empty($_GET('price'))){
$by = price;
}else{
$by = NAME;
}
if (!empty($_GET('price'))){
$order = $_GET['price'];
}else{
$order = ASC;
}
```

Как правильно сделать тоже самое? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $_GET('price')

надо поменять на

```
$_GET['price']
```

Comment: Да. верно. сразу не заметил.

Answer (score 0):

Что есть NAME и ASC ? может вы имели ввиду 'NAME' и 'ASC'
И вообще ваш код не безопасен. Или вы делаете платформу для обучения SQL инъекций?

Comment: NAME и ASC просто строки

Comment: Строки обрамляются кавычками `>_<`

Comment: Ну так я говорю, используйте их как строки, а именно с кавычками 'NAME' и 'ASC' или "NAME" и "ASC"